# Xcode 6.1 xib based app crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6.1

Does anyone have any ideas, this is killing me. Create an app from a Single View Application template, delete the storyboard and ViewController.swift file and then add a new view controller called `MainViewController` with a **Xib**.

Change the project settings for Main Interface from Main to `MainViewController` and run.

In previous versions of Xcode this would have worked fine. Now no matter what I try I cannot get this to work. Tried initialising the View Controller in the App Delegate but no joy, it just crashes with this exception:

```
2014-11-22 11:14:48.084 TestApp[9781:422842] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIApplication 0x7fd510611320> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key view.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001025c9f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010410dbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001025c9b79 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x00000001029e17b3 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000102513e80 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010311ac7d -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010311c722 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 160
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000102e54b11 -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 46
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000102e53c19 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1075
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000102e52bf2 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
    10  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000105cad2a3 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke + 16
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001024ff53c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001024f5285 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001024f5045 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001024f4486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000102e52669 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000102e55420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    17  TestApp                             0x00000001023e9cae top_level_code + 78
    18  TestApp                             0x00000001023e9cea main + 42
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001048e7145 start + 1
    20  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Please [search on the error message](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=NSUnknownKeyException+this+class+is+not+key+value+coding-compliant+for+the+key).

Comment: I have, extensively,  and can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a xib or storyboard file for the Main Interface. Not a ViewController.

Also make sure you don't have any dangling outlets. Make sure that the objects in the xib don't have an outlet set which does not exist in your ViewController.h or ViewController.m

Comment: Yup, as stated I've created the Xib, and there are no interface elements.